# Fastest Query to find records which have equal values and specific different value

Tags: sql

I have a table transactions with the following columns:
transactionId, systemId, subId and type

I need to find all transactionIds that have
subId and type as equals but different systemId

I tried the following query but I am not sure that it is the fastest query to use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT transactionId, T1.systemId  system1, 
T2.systemId  system2, T1.subId
FROM transactions T1
INNER JOIN transactions T2

WHERE T1.subId = T2.subId 
AND T1.type = T2.type

AND T1.systemId != T2.systemId
```

Comment: That's the only query you can use. If it's not fast, you're missing the right table index.

Comment: what is your RDBMS ?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a `GROUP BY` with a `HAVING` clause:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT transactionId
FROM t
GROUP BY transactionId, subId, type
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT systemId) > 1
```

Comment: One of the very few occasions where `select distinct` with `group by` is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

There are many factors that affect execution efficiency, and you can write all query for comparison.
such as

```sql
select *
  from (
select t1.*,
       count(distinct t1.systemId) over(partition by t1.type, t1.subId) cot
  from transactions t1
) t1
 where t1.cot > 1
;

select *
  from transactions t1
 where exists(
           select *
             from (
               select v1.type, v1.subId 
                 from transactions v1 
                group by v1.type, v1.subId 
               having count(distinct v1.systemId) > 1
            ) vv1
            where vv1.type = t1.type
              and vv1.subId = t1.subId
       )
;
```

Depending on the dbms you are using, there will be more different query ways